# Parallel running of Selenium Webdriver Specflow tests - static accessor cannot be used on multi thread execution

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, gherkin, extentreports

I've been running Selenium Webdriver tests with C# Specflow successfully including parallel testing using AssemblyInfo.cs attribute:

```
   [assembly: Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Fixtures)]
```

This was working fine but i had to add some static hooks [BeforeTestRun] and [BeforeFeature] and the Afters for extent report creation.
With static hooks it now throws the error:

Message: TechTalk.SpecFlow.SpecFlowException : The ScenarioStepContext.Current static accessor cannot be used in multi-threaded execution. Try injecting the scenario context to the binding class. See http://go.specflow.org/doc-multithreaded for details.

I've tried to implement context injection as recommended in the link(i thought i was doing this correctly in the first place) but I'm obviously doing something wrong.

```
    [Binding]
    public class SetupSteps : Steps
    {

        public IWebDriver driver;

        private readonly IObjectContainer objectContainer;
        private static WebDriverContext webDriverContext;

        private static ExtentReports extent;
        private static ExtentTest scenario;
        private static ExtentTest feature;

        public FeatureContext featureContext;
        public ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

        public SetupSteps(IObjectContainer container, ScenarioContext scenarioContext, FeatureContext featureContext) 
        {
            this.objectContainer = container;
            this.scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
            this.featureContext = featureContext;

        }

        [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void InitialiseReport()
        {
            only implemented for extent report..etc...
        }

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void TearDownReport()
        {
            extent.Flush(); 
        }

        [BeforeFeature]
        public static void BeforeFeature(FeatureContext featureContext)
        {
            feature = extent.CreateTest<Feature>(featureContext.FeatureInfo.Title);       
        }

        [AfterFeature]
        public static void AfterFeature()
        {
        }

        [BeforeScenario]
        public void Setup(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            scenario = feature.CreateNode<Scenario>(scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title);

            webDriverContext = new WebDriverContext();
            driver = webDriverContext.driver;
            objectContainer.RegisterInstanceAs<WebDriverContext>(webDriverContext);
            ...etc....
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            //close and disposes
        }
```

Any advice on why this is wrong? Removing the static accessor and adding parameters to the new hooks throws different BoDi errors. Many thanks.